# How do I get a backtrace of hanging Ruby process?

Tags: ruby, interrupt, backtrace

There is a complex testing suite with Capybara, Selenium, Allure and it's all abused:

- it launches and exits Chrome on its own, not leaving this job to Capybara
- before and after hooks are put in wrong places, causing such effects as, for example, filling remote DB when you do just `rspec --dry-run`
- Allure reports gem is pretty much abandoned and I believe is integrated here also not without wrong practices

Now when I run tests sometimes they hang, so I press `^C` but they don't stop:

```
RSpec is shutting down and will print the summary report... Interrupt again to force quit.
```

It does not stop no matter how long I wait and even when I close the browser manually.

When I press `^C` again it prints nothing -- no backtrace.
How do I know where it hangs? How do I get a backtrace of it at any moment?

Comment: use `gdb` to hook into the process and see what it is processing?

Comment: Julia Evans has a really good post about this - https://jvns.ca/blog/2016/06/12/a-weird-system-call-process-vm-readv/

Comment: Here's how to get a backtrace: https://isotope11.com/blog/getting-a-ruby-backtrace-from-gnu-debugger

Comment: Thanks! The `gdb ```which ruby``` --pid=31816` and `call rb_backtrace()` commands worked for me. (idk how to format backticks inside code in SO markdown)